# Persisting international and local time in MySQL db

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using MySQL DB for my application which is used worldwide. My application server and DB is deployed some where in my country. When user makes an entry I want to save that time too in my entry table. I'm not sure how will I do this, If I save current time or now() it will save local time which will be different from international time. How will I solve this, should I create 2 columns for my local server time and user local machine time. Please suggest.

Comment: save all your DT's as GMT ?

Comment: Not totally unrelated is [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900) and answers related to `SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";` and `SET @@session.time_zone = "+05:30";` ... then you need to do a lot of tinkering. It is a PITA but it is what it is